# Why do I get an Error when I am using GET with parameter

Tags: xamarin, webapi

I am trying to retrieve date from a MS SQL server via a WinApi. In image 1 I am calling GET (2nd image) with a parameter.
I set a breakpoint in Image 1 and when program hits the break point and I hove over "response" it shows that one record was retrieved.
When I continue and get to the break point in the 2nd image and hover over "userAuthentication" the result is "null".
I ran the url sting in Postman and it works.
One more bizarre thing. When a call GET without without a parameter it works, I am getting all records in "userAuthentication".

[image]
[image]

```
public async Task<List<UserAuthentication>> Get(string employeeNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Key", "1234");
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(@"http://192.168.100.223/api/Pilot?employeeID=" + employeeNumber) ;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAuthentication>>(response);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


public async void IsPilotAuthorized(string sEmployeeNum)
    {
        string dbPilotName = "";
        string dbPassword = "";
        string dbEmployeeNumber = "";
        int dbAccessAllowed = 0;
        int dbPFRID = 0;

        

        ApiService apiServices = new ApiService();
        var userAuthentication = new List<UserAuthentication>(); // = await apiServices.Get(sEmployeeNum);
        userAuthentication = await apiServices.Get("918374");

        userAuthentication[0].PilotName = dbPilotName;   
    }
```

Please see attached image for clarity. I created a new project and excluded any unnecessary code. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text and not as an image.

Comment: What is ApiService here? Can you please share us the code about ApiService ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the source code.

Comment: I still don't know what ApiService is? Is it a custom class your created or  a class from some third-part library?

Comment: ApiService is a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to check that Json result is an array or object.

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("your url")

var token = JToken.Parse(response);

if (token is JArray)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAuthentication>>(response)
}
else if (token is JObject)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserAuthentication>(response)
}
```

You can check the exception using below code.

```
try{
  ....code
}catch(Exception e){
   Debug.WriteLine(e)
}
```

Comment: Sorry jai, that didn't work.

Comment: can you please post your json response in case of passing parameter?

Comment: Jay. I am not sure that I understand your question. How do I capture the Jason Response?

Comment: This line doesn't work:   "return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserAuthentication>(response)" I get the following error:      "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Pilot_Sleep_Diary.Model.UserAuthentication' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Pilot_Sleep_Diary.Model.UserAuthentication>"

Comment: var response = await client.GetStringAsync(@"192.168.100.223/api/Pilot?employeeID=" + employeeNumber) ; Can you please provide "response" variable value i.e. what are you getting in response?

Comment: When I execute the program and hover with the mouse over "response" I can see that 1 record was retrieved and I can see that the data is correct. Its the return that's not working because in when I hover over "userAuthentication" in the "isPilotAuthorized" the return is "null"

Comment: var userAuthentication = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAuthentication>>(response); check userAuthentication here. Is it null or not. If it is null then make your deserialize object according to response.

Comment: Error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App4.Model.UserAuthentication]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'Id', line 2, position 7.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I was saying the same thing by check your json response. If your json response is Array then deserialize in List<T> otherwise normal object. If your problem has been fixed then please accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Jai, I figured it out. Thanks for all you help.